# Circular dependency when using static variable in Angular service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, circular-dependency

I have a service which contains a static variable `conceptionMode`, a class : `draw`, and the draw class has an event manager `eventManager`. I want that my EventManager access to the conceptionMode static variable.

**ConceptionService** (Angular service)

- conceptionMode: Enum
- draw: Class

**Draw** (class)

- eventManager: Class

**EventManager** (class)

{ methods with observables }

But the call `ConceptionService.conceptionMode` in EventManager methods causes circular dependency.
The idea is to stream events only if the conception is in a particular mode without injecting the entire ConceptionService.
The other solution is to check mode in destinations subscriptions but it could be less maintainable.

Comment: can you add the code for each class?

Comment: Sorry the code is under private license. What informations do you need ?

Comment: Did you find any solution to that problem? I am running in the same situation.